# Flutter Firebase - Update Document in Nested Collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a workout app where the user can create workouts and add exercises to that workout. In Firebase (see db screenshots), I have a "user_workouts" collection with an "exercises" nested collection. I would like the user to be able to add an exercise (name, reps and sets) for that particular workout.

First off...I think this is the proper syntax:

```
addExercise() {
  if (exerciseNameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('user_workouts')
        .doc(docId)
        .collection('exercises')
        .doc(docId)
        .update({
          'Exercise': exerciseNameController.text,
          'Reps': repsController.text,
          'Sets': setsController.text
        })
        .then((_) => print('Success'))
        .catchError((error) => print('Failed: $error'));
  }
}
```

Is this the correct syntax?  If so, how do I go about getting the 'docId' for each collection, instead of hardcoding it?
Here are the screenshots of my database:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What collection do you want to add a document to?

Comment: I want the new exercise that the user enters to be added to the "exercises" collection

Comment: The collection updates if I hardcode the DocIds.  I am stuck on how to get the appropriate DocIds that are auto generated when the user creates a new workout

Comment: You will need to remember them at that point, or (more likely) when you load the data from the database into the UI - to allow the user to edit it. If you don't know which document to update, the only thing you can do is update all of them - by first reading all the documents from the (sub)collection.

Comment: I actually don't think I want to update because that would continuously update the same document.  I want to be able to add a document to the nested "exercises" collection

Comment: To add a new document to the exercises` subcollection of a specific user, you will still need to know thd document ID of that user's document in the top-level `user_workouts` collection, and then call `add` on a reference to that collection.

Answer (score 1):

To update an existing document, you will need to know the complete path to that document already.

In most application you know the path, because you loaded the data from it already in order to display it. You will need to ensure you keep track of the necessary document IDs at that point.

If you don't know which document to update, the only thing you can do is update all of them - by first [reading all the documents from the (sub)collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).