# Flutter Firebase - Nested Collection Confusion

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a workout app and I am having difficulty with nested collections. I would like the user to be able to add multiple exercises to a specific workout. Based on the documentation, I have to somehow get the id for a workout and then reference it in order to add a collection to that ID, but I don't know how to do that (without hardcoding obviously). I've read through the documentation and can't find an answer that doesn't involve hardcoding the document ID. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Screenshot of Database

[image]

Again, I'd like the user to be able to add an "exercises" collection to the "Chest & Back" collection. The new "exercises" collection will have the fields: "Exercise", "Reps" and "Sets".

Thanks!

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996531/flutter-firebase-update-document-in-nested-collection)? As I answered there already, you will need to somehow *know* the relevant document ID, typically because you read it from the database to show the data in the UI.

Comment: Your answer both here and there is very vague. Obviously I have to know the doc id of the collection that the sub collection will be added to. That’s not the issue. I am having trouble actually fetching the relevant doc id without hardcoding it.

Comment: If my answer is vague, I recommend giving more detailed information on *how* you personally know which document you want to update. That exact same knowledge will need to be in your code.

Comment: Might I just add that after hours of reading through Firebase documentation and watching YouTube videos, Chat GPT ended up providing me with the exact answer I was looking for. As developers we should be worried that an AI bot can provide an answer in seconds. Why would a company pay an employee to help answer questions, when a 24/7 AI bot can for free

Comment: Good to hear you got it working Jeff.  --- Consider paying it forward and post an answer explaining in your own words what the cause of the problem was and how you solved it. Not only will that help other in the same situation who happen upon this post in the future, but it may also help train future LLMs on your answer just like they've been trained on answers that you have probably used from this site in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your add method;

```
final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Chest & Back')
    .doc(user?.uid)
    .collection('exercises')
    .doc();
     
db.set({
"Reps": "",
"Sets": "",
});
```

Comment: "Chest & Back" isn't fixed..the user enters whatever workout name they want. How would I reference the "Exercise" field that the user entered?